# Electron React : Unable to view console log from react

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have Electron app which access react app running on dev server. I use loadURL("http://localhost:3000/") to access the reactapp within electron.  The react app having console logs however not able to view the logs anywhere. how do I view these log messages

NB: I am new to JS /react/Electron and come from enterprise java background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the render process you can start here.
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging

for the main process you can see here.
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process

if you are using vscode you can use this handy guide.
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process-vscode

Comment: Actually i was not looking into browser console of electron I was looking at the console where i started the react and Electron for logs. Hence I was not able to view the log

Answer (score 0):

You need to [export environment variables](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/environment-variables)

POSIX shell example:

```
$ export ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true
$ electron
```

Windows console example:

```
> set ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true
> electron
```